# 3D Mouse Sensitivity Changes for no Reason

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-mouse

I have a 3DConnexion Space Navigator 3D mouse which I use for both Blender and SketchUp modeling. Sometimes while in Blender the panning sensitivity will change but the twisting sensitivity will stay the same. Restarting Blender solves the problem, but I would really like to know if there's a way I can prevent this from happening.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, though I own a 3d mouse and never saw this problem.

Comment: Uninstall and re-install the drivers for your device.

Comment: Well, from 3D Connexions side, Blender should be fully supported since 2.59: https://www.3dconnexion.de/nc/company/press-room/pressdetail/browse/3/article/3dconnexion-3d-mice-help-digital-artists-create-dazzling-3d-designs-in-blender-259.html?tx_ttnews%5BbackPid%5D=88&cHash=e61016efb3